# How to make empty datatbale to appear in aspx page?

Tags: vb.net

My scenario is,

I have created a page and made some changes by applying templates and gridview in Updatepanel.Now i have a footer template to add and insert the data to database.But it doesnt appear when the there is no data in datatable.

I need to show those footertemplate during page load event.and when i add it has to refresh the page to show the Datas. Please help on this

Page load event:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load, UpdatePanel1.Load

        If Not IsPostBack Then

            BindData()

        End If

    End Sub


Private Sub BindData()

        Dim strQuery As String = "select MembershipName,FamilyMember,MemberName,Dateofbirth from IOMFamilyDetails "

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)

        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(cmd)

        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options.

1. Try to add an empty data row as described in this article
   http://dotnetspidor.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-display-gridview-header-and.html
2. Create a custom gridview control by overriding the CreateChildControls method of the GridView control as described here http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/how_to_show_header_and_footer.html

Sorry both of them in C#.